# Force excel to import data from external sources as UTF-8 before it opens the file

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

What I wan't is to force default import data settings. So that in text import wizard the file origin will be set as UTF-8, or stated in VBA language: '.TextFilePlatform = 65001'. I can see that similar questions were asked already, however, none of them provides the answer I require. I want excel to be set at UTF-8 each time I try to open the file; no additional steps like opening/saving files as text, &c.